# Auto publish web application to file system after successful build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I have created a publish profile in VS2012 to publish the web application to a specified folder. However I need VS2012 to automatically publish it after a successful build. I went through all the project settings but did not find any hint.

Any solution to do this?

**EDIT**
To clarify, there are answers for doing this on TFS. but is there solution on developers local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `build definition` in `Team Explorer`, you adjust your directory deployement, you define `Build Default section` 
You remark path of deployement on picture

Note : you can specify UNC path.

[image]

Comment: But from my understanding, this is for dropping the output files. But this will also trigger the publish command?

Comment: no its for publish also, you can also define your proper path by using UNC, and you have last section who permit you to clean the not builded result, in order to dispose space on your server

Comment: i'am happy to help you Shuping

Answer (score 1):

When you publish it, it will automaticly (re-)build the web application

You could ,instead of re-build, click on the publish button.

Comment: what I want is that publish is triggered after build

Comment: why you don't publish it (with the button), then it will automaticly build and publish with one click

Comment: Because I want the publish happens after build on the build machine where there is nobody "clicking" on the nightly build machine.

Comment: @Shuping: you asked about Visual Studio and said nothing about TFS. Please update your question to say that you mean a TFS Team Build.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I would not constraint this to TFS, but would like see a general answer, for example how if the build sever is not TFS? is there any solution such as post build events in Visual Studio? So, I think this is more a Visual Studio setting or Configuration issue.

Comment: Then you need to clarify. Which "build machine" are you referring to? Do you mean, on the machine of the developer who happens to be building? Then just use Build->Deploy instead of Build->Build.

Comment: Yes, on the machine of developer. but I don't see a menu Build->Deploy